# Query a mongo db collection via a Spring Boot Rest API to return results in a paginated format

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-boot, mongotemplate

There is a collection present in Mongo that has a few attributes. This gets saved whenever any transaction happens in the engine. I need an API that enables the users to search the AnaysisJob by one or more combinations of the following attributes:
•   startedBy
•   startedAt (we’ll  need a “from” and “to” and we’re searching using a between clause).
•   status.

The users can search using a single attribute or a combination of the above attributes. If a combination is used then it must be “AND”ed.

Not to forget, it must support pagination too.

Below are the classes :

AnalysisJobSearchCriteria.java

```
@Data
@Document
public class AnalysisJobSearchCriteria {
    private Long startedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private String startedBy;
    private AnalysisJobStatusType status;
}
```

AnalysisJobResource.java

```
@Slf4j
@Api(value = "Analysis Job Resource", tags = "CONNECTIONS")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class AnalysisJobResource {

    @Autowired
    private AnalysisJobSearchService analysisJobSearchService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Analysis", response = Map.class)
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK")
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/analysis-job", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchAnalysisJob(@RequestBody final AnalysisJobSearchCriteria analysisJobSearchCriteria) {
        AggregationResults<AnalysisJobResource> analysisJob = analysisJobSearchService.searchAnalysisJobs(analysisJobSearchCriteria);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(analysisJob, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

AnalysisJobSearchService.java

```
@Service
public class AnalysisJobSearchService {

    private final AnalysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl analysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl;

     @Autowired
        public AnalysisJobSearchService(final AnalysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl analysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl) {
            this.analysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl = analysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl;
        }

    public AggregationResults<AnalysisJobResource> searchAnalysisJobs(AnalysisJobSearchCriteria analysisJobSearchCriteria) {
        AggregationResults<AnalysisJobResource> analysisJob = analysisJobCustomRepositoryImpl.searchAnalysisJob(analysisJobSearchCriteria);
        return analysisJob;
    }

}
```

AnalysisJobCustomRepository.java

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public AggregationResults<AnalysisJobResource> searchAnalysisJob(AnalysisJobSearchCriteria analysisJobSearchCriteria) {
    MatchOperation salaryMatch = null;
    if (!analysisJobSearchCriteria.getStatus().equals(null)) {
    salaryMatch = Aggregation.match(new Criteria("status").is(analysisJobSearchCriteria.getStatus()));
    }

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(salaryMatch);

    AggregationResults<AnalysisJobResource> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
            aggregation, "result", AnalysisJobResource.class);
    return result;
}
```

These are some of the classes I have. I also have a Connection class to establish connection with my database and the connection works fine. It is just that I am not able to come up with a query along with the mongo template for my scenario to work.

As I am new to using Mongo with Spring Boot, any kind of help would be appreciated. Also, I believe that it would be better if the service returns List rather than AggregationResult. But how to create a query in Java for Mongo has got me all confused.

Comment: I added the below method in my repository :
`@Override
 public List<AnalysisJob> searchAnalysisJob(AnalysisJobSearchCriteria analysisJobSearchCriteria) {
  Query query = new Query();
  query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("status").is(analysisJobSearchCriteria.getStatus()));
  log.info("Single Filter Only Query: {} ", query);
  List<AnalysisJob> analysisJobResource = mongoTemplate.find(query, AnalysisJob.class);
  
  return analysisJobResource;
 }`
But how do i manipulate the query as per my requirement. This gives me the basic result with equals criteria for status.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AggregationOperation for this issue

```
private List<SearcheableEntity> searchSmth(CustomCriteria criteria){

  List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();

  //it's simple way, better pattern is to create criteria builder, 
  //witch will create Criteria.class object from request params
  operations.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name").is(criteria.getName());

  //For pagination skip and limit methods can be used
  operations.add(Aggregation.skip(criteria.getOffset() != null ? criteria.getOffset() : 0));
  operations.add(Aggregation.limit(criteria.getLimit() != null ? criteria.getLimit() : Integer.MAX_VALUE));

  return mongoTemplate
                .aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(operations),
                           "Collection_name", 
                           SearcheableEntity.class
                ).getMappedResults();
}
```

Also if you need to have logical OR or AND on in your search you can create search criteria in such patterns

```
new Criteria().andOperator(firstCrinteria, ..., lastCriteria)
new Criteria().orOperator(firstCrinteria, ..., lastCriteria)
```

For your example

```
SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<AnalysisJobResource> searchAnalysisJob(AnalysisJobSearchCriteria criteria) {
  List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();

  if (!criteria.getStatus() != null) {
     operations.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("status").is(criteria.getStatus())));
  }
  if(!criteria.getStartedAt().equals(null)){ 
  operations.add(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("time").gt(criteria.getStartedAt()));
  }

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        Aggregation.newAggregation(operations), "result", AnalysisJobResource.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pagination you can use `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` and `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` from Spring Data as it's described in the below article

https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-paging/

Also for searching to MongoDB database it's ok to use Criteria, because it allow you to add dynamically AND / OR clause to your query. You could find an article about how to use Criteria with Spring Data and MongoDB below

https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb